# open ssl converting pfx to pem and password protecting pem

Tags: openssl, pem, pfx

I was using openssl to convert a pfx (containing private key, and server, intermediate and root certificates provided by CA) to pem. The pfx is password protected, having to enter that when prompted in openssl, but after converting to pem, I found that the resultant pem wasn't password protected. I kinda presumed the pw would carray ver. Is there a way to bring along the pfx password to the pem and would password protecting this file on the os level this have any TLS impacts once it's deployed? I don't think it would. thank you very much for reading this.

openssl pkcs12 -in my_pfx -out my.pem -nodes